# Plotting a two parameter function evaluated at a specific point

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages, parametric-functions

I am trying to solve the following problem: given the differential equation  $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\bigg(a+b\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}x\bigg)y=0$$
subjected to two different initial condition we get two different solution lets call them $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$. Now I have to plot the following expression 
$$z(a,b)=|y_1\partial_xy_2-y_2\partial_xy_1|\bigg|_{x=0}$$
To implement it I have written following code

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + (a + b (2 + 2/Pi ArcTan[x])) y[x] == 
0, y[-10] == Exp[I 10 Sqrt[a + b]], 
y'[-10] == -I Sqrt[a + b]*Exp[I 10 Sqrt[a + b]]}, 
y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]

u = ParametricNDSolve[{z''[x] + (a + b (2 + 2/Pi ArcTan[x])) z[x] == 
0, z[10] == Exp[-I 10 Sqrt[a + 3 b]], z'[10] == -I Sqrt[a + 3 b]*Exp[I 10 Sqrt[a + 3 b]] },z, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[s[a, b][x] D[u[a, b][x], x] /. 
 x -> 0 - D[s[a, b][x], x] u[a, b][x] /. x -> 0]], {a, 0, 5} {b, 0, 5}]
```

The first two lines of the code(solving the equation) are correct. I have checked them. Its the third line where the code seems to not work. It gives me the error

> $a\{0,5\}$ is not of the form $\{x,xmin,xmax\}$.

Can someone help me figure out where I am making the mistake?

Comment: You haven't understood the usage of `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) and `Rule` (`->`), please check the document of them carefully. Also, you've missed a `,` between `{a, 0, 5} {b, 0, 5}`. One way to fix is: `Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[y[a, b][x] D[z[a, b][x], x]  - D[y[a, b][x], x] z[a, b][x] ]/.x->0/.s/.u], {a, 0, 5} ,{b, 0, 5}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With little modifications it seems to wotk:

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[2][y][x] + (a + b*(2 + (2/Pi)*ArcTan[x]))*y[x] == 0, y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]], 
    Derivative[1][y][-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a + b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]]}, y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]

u = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[2][z][x] + (a + b*(2 + (2/Pi)*ArcTan[x]))*z[x] == 0, z[10] == Exp[(-I)*10*Sqrt[a + 3*b]], 
    Derivative[1][z][10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a + 3*b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + 3*b]]}, z, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[(s[a, b][0] Derivative[1][u[a, b]][0]) -
      (Derivative[1][s[a, b]][0] u[a, b][0])]], {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but can you tell specifically what mistake am I making. Also when you wrote Derivative[1]u[a,b][0] which derivative will it be i.e. with respect to which variable a,b,x?

Comment: With your approach you have to make additional substitutioin: `y/.s` etc., using `ParametricNDSolveValue` returns just `IinterpolationFunction` (not your `y->InterpolationFunction[...]`). Derivative is with respect to argument of function, i.e. `x`: function is `u[a,b]` anf it's argument is `x`, and derivative is taken at value of argument is equal to 0, you may find this in help on `Derivative`.